# Python : No translation file found for domain using custom locale folder

Tags: python, gettext

I have the following structure :

```
/
|- main.py
|- brainz
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- Brainz.py
|- datas
     |- locale
          |- en_US
               |- LC_MESSAGES
                    |- brainz.mo
                    |- brainz.po
```

In my `__init__.py` there is the following lines :

```
import locale
import gettext
import os

current_locale, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()

locale_path = '../datas/locale/' + current_locale + '/LC_MESSAGES/'

language = gettext.translation ( 'brainz', locale_path )
language.install()
```

But when I try to run my program I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from brainz.Brainz import *
  File "/home/damien/BrainZ/brainz/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    language = gettext.translation ( 'brainz', locale_path )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gettext.py", line 484, in translation
    raise IOError(ENOENT, 'No translation file found for domain', domain)
IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'brainz'
```

I don't understand which path is expected by `gettext.translation` as I give a complete path to the `.mo` file.

Could someone explain me what I have to do to load my translation files correctly ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: try locale_path set to full path for example : locale_path="/home/xxx/"

Comment: @john misoskian It doesn't works too... domain argument (1st argument of gettext.translation) is set to 'brainz'. I suppose it is the reference to the filename (brainz.mo). Is it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your `__init__.py` should be something like:

```
import locale
import gettext
import os

current_locale, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()

locale_path = 'datas/locale/'
language = gettext.translation ('brainz', locale_path, [current_locale] )
language.install()
```