# IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'wtforms'

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm building a Flask app with Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7. I got this error when I try to open a page with a wtforms inside:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'wtforms'

I created a virtualenv environment and installed the required packages. Every other page that has not a wtform works fine.

Comment: That error comes from `gettext`. It looks like your app has localization support included. Is the locale setup correctly? [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3837683/445073) may help you.